# Qt: Setting the app-icon on Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, qt, icons, qt-creator

I'm developing an App that is supposed to run on
Windows, MacOSX, Android, and iOS.

I found out how to set the icon on Windows and Mac, but how does it work on Android and iOS?

Thanks for reading!

EDIT: I do not use Nessecitas SDK. There is no AndroidManifest.xml in my project folder. However, there is a folder in the same directory as my project-folder called "build-myProjectName-Android_f_r_armeabi_GCC_4_8_Qt_5_3_1-Release", which contains a folder "android-build", which contains a manifest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should create an Android manifest file and edit it in Qt Creator.

Since Qt 5.4 along with QtCreator 3.3.0, you should go to **Projects > Build Android APK > Details**

Now Select **Create Templates** to create the manifest file and to open it in editor :

[image]

As shown in the picture, you can set three versions of icons for your application with low, medium, and high DPI values, from left to right.

In previous versions of Qt and Qt Creator you should go to **Projects->Run->Deploy** and select **Create AndroidManifest.xml** button.

Answer (score 1):

in your android manifest there is a line
`android:icon="@drawable/launcher_icon"`
set your icon name here and thats it
while in iOS you can use image assets to easily drag and drop icons and splashscreens

Comment: I don't have an AndroidManifest.xml in my project folder. Where can i find it? Oh, i do _not_ use Nessecitas SDK if that matters. Let me edit the main post.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new project in eclipse will create a launcher icon with the name ic_launcher(Can be changed) in 4 different sizes as the http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html says 48*48,72*72,96*96 and 144*144 and these icons can be found in mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi and xxhdpi folders respsetively. Change these icons as u required. You can check the manifest.xml file and see  android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" has been set.